# Calculate a trigonometric limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate the limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x\cos(x-1)-1}{x-1}$$

I manipulated the expression to get:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin^2(x-1) }{(x-1)^2} \frac{-x(x-1) }{\cos(x-1)+1}$$

But I can't use $\lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ because obviously x is not approaching 0, what can I do in order to calculate this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Identify the limit as being the derivative of $x\mapsto x\cos(x-1)$ at $1$.

Comment: Denote $t=x-1$, then you'll get $t\to 0$

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Yes, you *can* use $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, because your quantity $x-1$ has limit $0$ as $x\to1$.

Comment: I used $ t=x−1 $ but then I get that the limit is $0$ where the original limit is 1, how do I get to the right answer?

Comment: @user1326293 You must have made some mistake in your manipulation. Indeed the limit of the expression you came up with, as $x\to 0$, is $0$. You might consider a more direct approach, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More directly, letting $y=x-1$ your original limit becomes$$\require\cancel \lim_{y\to0}\frac{(y+1)\cos y-1}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\cancel{y}\cos y}{\cancel{y}}+\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\cos y-1}{y}=\cos0+0=1. $$

Answer (score 7):

You could do a change of variable. Let $y=x-1$, and then your expression changes to:

$$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(y) }{(y)^2} \frac{-(y+1)(y) }{\cos(y)+1}$$

Does that help?

Comment: it seems like this is the way to go, but I get that the limit is zero, and the answer is 1, what have I done wrong?
I just evaluated the lim as $y \to 0$

Comment: There must be some problem with how you went from the original expression, which has a limit of 1, to your second expression, which has a limit of 0. Double-check your work there.

Comment: Vicenzo's answer is a good one, using the substitution right off the bat.